# I keep getting the error invalid use of incomplete type 'struct familyFinace' how do I fix this?

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

I am trying to append a node but I keep getting the error incomplete type 'struct familyFinace' how do I fix this?

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <familyFinance>

using namespace std;
struct familyFinance{                     
  int acctNos; float Balance; familyFinance *nextNodePointer;  familyFinance *ptrHead;  familyFinance *dynFinancePtr;
      };

void printOnesBelowThreshold (float , int [], float [], int );
void spitThemOut(struct familyFinace);
void anyBelowThreshold(struct familyFinance [], int , float,
      struct familyFinance &); 

int main() {
 

  int noAccounts = 7, Option; float Threshold;
  struct familyFinance startNodeOption3 ;

  familyFinance financeAry[10];

  ifstream Lab3DataFileHandle;
  int num;
  float money;
 
familyFinace *ptrHead=nullptr;
familyFinace *dynFinancePtr=nullptr;
 familyFinace *tempPtr;
 tempPtr=ptrHead;

  Lab3DataFileHandle.open("Lab5Data.txt");
  while (!Lab3DataFileHandle.eof( )) {
    familyFinance *dynFinancePtr= new familyFinance;


 Lab3DataFileHandle >> dynFinancePtr -> acctNos; 
 Lab3DataFileHandle >> dynFinancePtr -> Balance;
 
 familyFinace  *ggnextNodePointer = nullptr;
  if (ptrHead == nullptr)  
   familyFinance *ptrHead  = dynFinancePtr;
else {      
 tempPtr =  ptrHead;
```

> down bellow is the main problem with the code on these lines I get invalid use of incomplete type 'struct familyFinace'

```
 while  (tempPtr -> nextNodePointerx != nullptr )
    tempPtr = tempPtr->nextNodePointer;
      tempPtr->nextNodePointer = dynFinancePt
```

Comment: With the given code it is impossible to help you. Try to boil the problem down to a minimal example containing all relevant parts.

Comment: What is `familyFinace` supposed to be?  There is no mention of that type anywhere in this code. And why are you implementing a linked-list manually instead of using `std::list` or `std::forward_list`?

Comment: It seems unlikely that code produces that error message since `familyFinace` appears nowhere within it. Seems like you got confused about what code you are actually compiling.

Comment: I just edited the question the proper code is now up.

Comment: Is it just a typo? `familyFinace` should be `familyFinance`?

Comment: You did not show your header file, so we can't say much here. The code as is now compiles in g++ 5.4.0 if the header is commented out and the missing braces at the end are added.

Comment: One error is here, `void spitThemOut(struct familyFinace);` it should be `void spitThemOut(familyFinance);`. You are asking for trouble by repeatedly using the keyword `struct` where it isn't needed. If you make a typo (like the example I mentioned) then the `struct` keyword is going to hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > invalid use of incomplete type 'struct familyFinace'
>
> how do I fix this?

Include the header for `familyFinance` before using the type. The compiler needs to see how the type is declared before you can use it.

Answer (score -1):

An incomplete type error can in some cases be fixed by forward declaration. Just put `struct familyFinance` somewhere in the global scope above the line that produces this error, e.g. right after `using namespace std;`

Comment: Incomplete type errors are **caused** by forward declarations. A class that has only been forward declared is an incomplete type.